# Iterated sums--something like a differsum

Tags: reference-request, cv.complex-variables, sequences-and-series

So I've been fiddling around with the cauchy product of sequences lately, and am curious about a little identity I've found (which I'm sure is ubiquitous in finite differences, as I can't be the only one to have thought of it). I have been having trouble proving it, but the idea is rather straight forward. I think I might have seen it somewhere before but can't find any literature on the subject through searches and am exhausted for a proof (even though I know it should be simple).

Consider a ring of sequences $a:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ endowed with the usual addition $+$ and the multiplication operator $\times$ where

$$(a \times b)(n) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j b_{n-j}$$

The first identity, which at hand is very simple to prove, follows from associativity of the product. Firstly

$$(a \times 1)(n) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j$$

and

**I am correcting the terrible mistake I made**

$$1 \times 1 \times ...(k\,times)...\times 1 = \dbinom{n+k-1}{k-1}$$

**end of terrible mistake**

giving the usual iterated sum formula

**edited to not be a terrible mistake**

$$\sum^k a(n) =  (a\times \dbinom{n+k-1}{k-1})$$

$$\sum^k a(n) = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j\dbinom{n+k-1-j}{k-1}= \sum_{n_{k-1}=0}^n \sum_{n_{k-2}=0}^{n_{k-1}}...k\,times...\sum_{n_0=0}^{n_1} a(n_0)$$

where $\sum^{k}\sum^{j} = \sum^{k+j}$. The question I am curious about is if this has ever been investigated for complex numbers--i.e; does anyone have any references to the operator

$$\sum^{s} a = \sum_{j=0}^n a_j \dbinom{n+s-j-1}{s-1}$$

and if perhaps it satisfies the identity

$$\sum^{s} \sum^{q} = \sum^{s+q}$$

so that it forms a sort of differsum (like a differintegral but with sums). By associativity of the Cauchy product the semigroup property is equivalent to showing

**edited to remove the typo**
$$\sum_{j=0}^n \dbinom{j+s-1}{s-1}\dbinom{n+q-j-1}{q-1} = \dbinom{n+s+q-1}{s+q-1}$$

which follows for $s,q \in \mathbb{N}$ (by the above) but I am unsure for $\Re(s),\Re(q) > 0$.

This is something I imagine must be somewhere in the vastness of literature on calculus of variations or finite differences. A proof or a reference to a proof is what I'm really looking for. I'm particular to a reference though, as I'd like to read what else people have written on the subject.

**the typo was the whole problem to be honest, I just made a typo. /shameface**

Comment: This is  the  discrete convolution,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution 
In the particular case of sequences $u:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{C}$ supported on $\mathbb{Z}_+$, it is also called "one-side convolution", and corresponds to the  Cauchy product of power series.

Comment: @PietroMajer I'm well aware of that, I guess I didn't make myself clear enough. I was more interested in the properties of the iterated sum, and then the complex iterated sum. If this construction exists in literature somewhere.

Comment: This fails when $n=0,$ right?

Comment: And this even fails for positive integers $s$ and $q$.  Right?

Comment: Should it be $1\times\ldots\text{($k$ times)}\ldots\times 1 = {n+k-1\choose k-1}$?

Comment: @JulianRosen I feel like such a tool right now. I can't believe I missed that there was a $k$ in the upper argument. I can't even understand how I missed that. Everything is as clear as day now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Fixing the typo in the post, we can prove the claim without much trouble.

After fixing the typo, the question is really asking to prove the following for all nonnegative integers $n$ and all complex $s$ and $q$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} {k+s-1 \choose k} {n-k + q-1 \choose n-k} = {n+q+s-1 \choose n},
$$
where ${z \choose n} = \frac{z(z-1)(z-2)\cdots (z-n+1)}{n!}$.

This is easy with generating functions.  Define the formal power series $$G_s (x) = \sum_{n=0} ^{\infty} {n+s-1 \choose n} x^n.$$  Then the claim is the same as showing $G_s(x) G_q (x) = G_{s+q} (x).$  But this follows immediately from the fact that 
$$
G_s (x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n+s-1 \choose n} x^n = \frac{1}{(1-x)^{s}}.
$$

See [this link for more](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Comment: I don't see how the OP's question is asking what you say it is really asking (which is a form of the well-known Chu-Vandermonde identity). But perhaps the OP should clarify what is meant by the expression $\binom{n}{s}$ (for complex $s$): is it $\frac{\Pi(n)}{\Pi(s)\Pi(n-s)}$ where $\Pi(s) := \int_0^\infty x^s e^{-x} dx$?

Comment: What he asked is false and not analogous with his convolution formula.  His convolution formula is supposed to be that of my post when $s$ is a positive integer.  In his notation, $1\times 1$ is supposed to have generating function $1/(1-x)^2$, but his didn't.

Comment: Even after fixing the typo, I still don't understand how this would answer the (fixed-up) question. Roughly speaking: how is an expression of type $\binom{\text{integer}}{s}$, by my reading a *transcendental function* in the complex variable $s$, supposed to relate to expressions of type $\binom{z}{\text{integer}}$ which are polynomials in $z$?

Comment: It's supposed to be ${n+s-1 \choose s-1} = {n+s-1 \choose n}$

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry -- I wasn't reading sufficiently carefully.

Comment: OH my god. That was my problem! I had the wrong indexes! I hate when I do this. I feel like such a fool right now. That was the only problem!

Comment: (Happens to me all the time.)

Comment: I feel bad because in my research this actually makes my proof of something way bigger incredibly easier. Like so incredibly easier 
I can't believe I made that mistake. Quite literally it was the only thing stopping me from completing the goal.

Comment: I just read that MO post about if someone on MO answers your question and solves something important to your research--should you reference them or not?  So I'm not sure how to thank you.

Comment: Oh.  In this case, don't bother with anything.  It's really nothing.

Comment: Well you at least get a winky face. Ty. ;) this made my day.